# Trust between NT4 samba domain and AD samba domain: which direction?

Tags: samba4

I would need to set a trust relation between a NT4 samba domain and another samba domain but AD.

The trust does not need to be bi-directional and either way is fine.

Which way does it work given both samba versions are 4.7.3?

Where can I find documentation on this issue?

Comment: Curious - What are you doing that the direction doesn't matter?

Comment: I have an existing NT4 domain with users and resources. We are rolling up a new AD domain, but in the meanwhile we need users on AD access resources on NT4. If NT4 trustes AD they simply access their shares where access control is by-group (simply add news groups to allowed grups). If AD trustes NT4, join AD machine to new domain and have users login to old domain.